# iOS Chromecast sdk does not resume session after wifi has been switched off and on again

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

When I add a `GCKUICastButton` to my app and connect to a cast receiver app, the google sdk connects to the receiver, and the button gets shown in the connected (filled) state. The following happens whether I start casting a video or not (according to Google's test cases resuming a session is not necessary/happening when no video is casting - but it should if a video is casting).

When I now switch off the Wifi, after a while the sdk detects the Wifi connection is missing, and removes the cast button.

Switching Wifi on again after a while (20 seconds) gets the sdk to detect cast devices again, and it displays the cast button - however, it does not resume the previous session (the receiver app is still running).

I remember this working a few months ago, and when I look into the cast sdk debug logs I see that on losing Wifi it seems to *end* the session instead of suspending it, so when Wifi comes on again it says `No Session to resume`.

Ending session statement in log:

`[GCKSessionManager notifyDidEndSession:error:] - Session ... ended with error Error Domain=com.google.cast.GCKError Code=17 "Network not reachable" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Network not reachable}`

No session to resume statement in log:

`[GCKSessionManager handleNetworkReachabilityChange:] - No session to resume`

Do others also experience this issue, and if so is there anything that can be done about it?

Comment: What did you set for `GCKCastOptions.suspendSessionsWhenBackgrounded`?

Comment: I do not set it explicitly, should be `true` by default

Comment: btw, Google's sample app shows the same behaviour, as do Netflix and some other streaming apps that can cast, so I tend to blame it on the current CastSDK ...

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behavior when I switch to the lock screen of a device. Have you found a way to resolve this issue ?